# Spring Boot Hibernate throws constraint warning on first startup with empty database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Spring Boot application and I want to create the tables with Entity annotations. When I run the jar, the application starts without warning if the tables already exist.
But if it the database is empty then I get these warnings for every table:

```
GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table mytable drop constraint if exists FKk53mrkxu32slsax6fmn164ijy" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table mytable drop constraint if exists FKk53mrkxu32slsax6fmn164ijy" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final] (....)
```

And:

```
2020-05-15 11:23:24.998  WARN 20319 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2020-05-15 11:23:24.998  WARN 20319 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : table "mytable" does not exist, skipping
```

The application works fine even with these warning, so is there a way to resolve the problem or to suppress the warnings?

My application.properties database related lines:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.initialize=true

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

**Update:**
The first longer exception only occurs if the table has a foreign key and the end of the exception looks like:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "mytable" does not exist
```

or

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "student_x_course" does not exist
```

After the exceptions Hibernate runs the CREATE TABLE ... sql statements.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my application.properties to hide the warnings :

```
logger.org.hibernate=error
```

Answer (score -1):

try to verify that your table "mytable" exist and i think you must change

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: I want to use import.sql though and it only works with create or create-drop.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`.
Or initialize database by script. Add schema.sql file with creation script in resources folder, and change ddl-auto to none.